# Does the White Album 2 anime share the same storyline as the visual novel?

Tags: white-album-2

I want to start watching the White Album 2 anime but I want to play the VN also.

I heard that the story from the anime is different than the game. Is this true? Because I would rather play the game first if it's the same story, but if it's an new anime original story I will watch it first.

Comment: I haven't watched the anime so I'm leaving this as a comment rather than a full answer, but I was under the impression that the anime is following the Opening Chapter part at least fairly accurately. One source of confusion might be between WA and WA2; see [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5484/how-are-white-album-and-white-album-2-related).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the anime does take some liberties between the two. The visual novel and anime do follow more or less the same path in the end and do converge but there are some differences.

However, note that the plots remain fairly similar despite this. I haven't looked at the next Visual Novel after *Introductory Chapter* yet but since they both end fairly similar one can imagine that the differences aren't large enough that you couldn't skip Introductory Chapter and go straight to the next chapter after watching the anime.

[The differences are large enough that the Baka Tsuki project does not want anyone translating purely off the anime:](http://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=White_Album_2)

> **Can I use stuff based on what I've seen in the anime?**
>
> Not really... the anime takes its liberties with the adaptation, even
> though it's done very well. There are some aspects that are shared
> between the game and anime, but please don't try a 1:1 copy of
> anything in-between.

**It's worth noting White Album 2's Introductory Chapter (the arc in which the anime covers is kinetic.** This means there will not be choices to make and it will be fairly linear. So, divergence will not be massive.

That said, I'll leave this as it is and keep spoilers out. If so desired, I can add more information under a spoiler tag listing some major differences.

Comment: I'm curious about scene differences since the Visual Novel only has "Single Ending" and "Linear Plot" tags on [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v2920), through the H Scenes you proably only need to mention them if they have been altered to the extent like with Shiro's and Saber's first H Scene in Fate/Stay Night

Comment: That's right -- it's single ending. Did I contradict myself somewhere and not notice it?

Comment: sorry, missed some words in my comment. alot of Visual Novels i know have multiple routes/endings and some adaptions of them try and include all of them. since there is a "Linear Plot" tag that would mean what choices there are don't amount to much...though i haven't played the Visual Novel yet (just basing it from Sono Hanabira where the next scene plays out slightly differently like choosing how Sara address Kaede when dressed up as a maid) so i'm curious of the major differences

Comment: As I noted, it's kinetic so there are no choices. Or are you just interested in the change set in general? It'll take some time to fully list them but if there's some people out there that want to know, I can rack my brain and come up with a few of the bigger ones.

Comment: change set in general but that's just me