# What happens after the ending of White Album 2 anime?

Tags: white-album-2

I want to know what happens after the ending of *White Album 2* anime, especially what happens to Kazusa and Haruki in the end.

I couldn't find an English version of the manga too.

What happens next?

Comment: Related: [Does the White Album 2 anime share the same storyline as the visual novel?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/6329). Might be a duplicate: [Does Touma Kazusa love Haruki in White album 2 anime and visual novel?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/38988)

Answer (score 0):

First off, just to clear things up, *White Album* 2 is based on a visual novel, not a manga. Now that I got that out of the way, let me begin.

*White Album 2* (the visual novel) is followed up by *White Album 2: Closing Chapter* in which there are two endings; one in which Haruki decides to be with Setsuna, and the other is to move on from Kazusa. If you chose the former, you will unlock *White Album 2: Coda* which is pretty much the final chapter of the series. In it, you can make Haruki end up with Kazusa or just let him be with Setsuna. After that, nothing much.

However, if you choose Kazusa's true ending, you will get the mini-drama CD which is an audio story which shows Haruki and Kazusa's life married. It's great and I will recommend it to any Kazusa fans out there.

If you want to read *Closing Chapter*, you can find a few Let's Plays on YouTube. However, if you want to read *Coda*, sadly it hasn't been translated yet, but YouTuber Pandaum has thankfully made a complete Let's Play of Kazusa's out of him explaining the events in texts. Hopefully, this helps you in understanding the events after the anime.

Comment: Has potential to be a good answer. I suggest separating your answer into different paragraphs to make it more readable. Also, include relevant sources/references.